# Calculadora em JavaScript selecionar o tipo de operação

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema nessa calculadora, a primeira imagem funciona corretamente, mas na segunda imagem não estou conseguindo pega o tipo da operação aritmética.

Segue o código da segunda imagem.

```js
function calcular() {
  var tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
  var tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
  var operacao = window.document.getElementById('operacao')
  var resultado = window.document.getElementById('resultado')
  var n1 = Number(tn1.value)
  var n2 = Number(tn2.value)
  if (operacao == 'Soma') {
    var s = n1 + n2
  }


  resultado.innerHTML = `A ${operacao} entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${s}`
}
```

```html
<div id="area" name="area">
  <h2>CALCULANDO VALORES...</h2>
  <input type="number" name="textn1" id="txtn1" placeholder="Primeiro Valor">
  <input type="number" name="textn2" id="txtn2" placeholder="Segundo Valor">
  <label for="operacao">Selecione a operação:</label>
  <select name="operacao" id="operacao">
    <option value="adicao">Adição</option>
    <option value="subtracao">Subtração</option>
    <option value="multiplicacao">Multiplicação</option>
    <option value="divisao">Divisão</option>
  </select>


  <!-- <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Soma" onclick="soma()">
        <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Sutração" onclick="subtracao()">
        <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Multiplicação" onclick="multiplicacao()">
        <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Divisão" onclick="divisao()">-->
  <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
  <div id="resultado" name="resultado">Resultado</div>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow, poste seu código por completo para que possa te ajudar melhor e mais rapido.

Answer (score 3):

O que está faltando em seu código para resolver o problema é obter o valor do `select` para realizar a comparação.

> O método [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) retorna a referência do elemento através
>   do seu ID, sendo o elemento uma referência a um objeto [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element), ou `null` se um elemento com o ID especificado não estiver contido neste documento.

A classe **Element** fornece alguns métodos e propriedades que são úteis quando estamos manipulando seus objetos e neste caso utilizaremos a propriedade `value` para obter o valor selecionado do `select`.

```js
function calcular() {
  var tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1');
  var tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2');

  var operacao = window.document.getElementById('operacao');
  var resultado = window.document.getElementById('resultado');

  var n1 = Number(tn1.value);
  var n2 = Number(tn2.value);

  var operador = operacao.value; //Obtendo o valor do <option> selecionado
  if (operador == 'adicao') {
    var s = n1 + n2;
  }
  if (operador == 'subtracao') {
    var s = n1 - n2;
  }
  if (operador == 'multiplicacao') {
    var s = n1 * n2;
  }
  if (operador == 'divisao') {
    var s = n1 / n2;
  }


  resultado.innerHTML = `A ${operador} entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${s}`
}
```

```html
<div id="area" name="area">
  <h2>CALCULANDO VALORES...</h2>
  <input type="number" name="textn1" id="txtn1" placeholder="Primeiro Valor">
  <input type="number" name="textn2" id="txtn2" placeholder="Segundo Valor">
  <label for="operacao">Selecione a operação:</label>
  <select name="operacao" id="operacao">
    <option value="adicao">Adição</option>
    <option value="subtracao">Subtração</option>
    <option value="multiplicacao">Multiplicação</option>
    <option value="divisao">Divisão</option>
  </select>
  <input name="calcular" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
  <div id="resultado" name="resultado">Resultado</div>

</div>
```

**Observação:** Perceba que as strings de comparação (`adicao`, `subtracao`, `multiplicacao` e `divisao`) são iguais aos valores das opções que compõe o seu `select`. Ou seja, quando você seleciona uma opção do elemento `select`, o valor do `select` é definido pelo atributo `value` do elemento `option` selecionado.

Comment: Victor, sua resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade por algum usuário. Eu recomendaria você explicar com texto o que você fez que resolveu o problema. Só postar o código pode não ser tão claro para todos os usuários. Por exemplo, não está claro porque passou de `== "Soma"` da pergunta para `== "adicao"` na sua resposta e isso é essencial para entender o que foi feito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, se tu sabe a resposta e a explicação, porque não posta?

Comment: @EdwardRamos Porque sei que o Victor fará isso, não vejo a necessidade de responder para colocar a mesma coisa

Comment: Eu estou atualizando a resposta galera, só não detalhei antes porque estava com outras tarefas aqui então só postei a solução... Guenta ai kkk Obrigado pelas observações.